# Node.js output formatting of big numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, factorial

I'm trying to write factorial implementation on `node.js`. From very simple recursive approach to most complex algorithms. Here is the code:

```
process.stdin.resume();

var i = 0, t = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', function (n) {
    if (t == 0) {
        t = n;
    } else {
        if (i++ < t) {
            process.stdout.write(Factorial(n).toString());
            if (i == t) {
                process.exit();
            }
        } else {
            process.exit();
        }
    }
});

function Factorial (n) {
    if (n > 1) {
        n *= Factorial(n - 1);
    }
    return n;
}
```

The problem is — the numbers representation. I expect to have precise answer:

`100! = 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000`

but I'm receiving more logical but useless for me at the moment:

`100! = 9.33262154439441e+157`

I believe binary representation of the factorial is correct, but how I could get 'loose' form of it?

Comment: JavaScript numbers are double-precision IEEE floating point. You can't represent `100!` accurately with native JavaScript numbers, I'm afraid.

Comment: That is a _massive_ number. If it takes 32 bits to represent 4294967295, it would take in excess of 512 bits to represent `100!` to the precision you are asking.

Comment: You could use a [bignum](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum) or [bigint](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js) JS library. I don't know if any support factorial, but you could implement it easily with multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use any of these:

- [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js)
- [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js)
- [javascript-bignum](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum)
- [jsbn.js](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/)

Implementing a function that computes factorials on top of any of these should be pretty straightforward. If you do so, you might want to use [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to improve the overall performance. Here is a basic implementation without big integer support:

```
var MEMOIZED_FACT = [];

function FACT(number) {
  var n = Math.floor(number);
  if (n === 0 || n === 1) {
    return 1;
  } else if(MEMOIZED_FACT[n] > 0) {
    return MEMOIZED_FACT[n];
  } else {
    return MEMOIZED_FACT = FACT(n - 1) * n;
  }
}
```